# How to update/insert annotation for objectPropertyAssertion with sparql?

Tags: sparql, ontology, graphdb

[How to insert object property and insert annotation  owl:Axiom describe like #DiseaseSite ?
thank you so much !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBMXa.png)

```
    INSERT {
    data:Bọ_Xích_Dài data:hasSymptom data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
    data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát data:isSymptomOf data:Bọ_Xích_Dài.
   ?annotation data:DiseaseSite "Hat"
}
where{
    ?annotation owl:annotatedSource data:Bọ_Xích_Dài;
               owl:annotatedProperty data:hasSymptom;
               owl:annotatedTarget data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
}
```

> how to insert axiom like the script below

```
<owl:Axiom>
<owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#Bọ_Xích_Xanh"/>
<owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#hasSymptom"/>
<owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#Hạt_bị_lửng"/>
<DiseaseSite rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Hạt</DiseaseSite>
</owl:Axiom>
```

Comment: PREFIX data: <http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
INSERT {
   ?annotation data:DiseaseSite "Hat"
}
where{
 ?annotation owl:annotatedSource data:Bọ_Xích_Dài;
               owl:annotatedProperty data:hasSymptom;
               owl:annotatedTarget data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
}
#mycode

Comment: is your comment the answer now? If so, please post it as a dedicated answer, if not, edit your question and add the query there.

Comment: It can only be resolved when the object property is already available when added with Protege. My problem here is that when adding new object property and annotation for object property, it is not possible. Bro !

Comment: `INSERT {data:Bọ_Xích_Dài data:hasSymptom data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
 data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát data:isSymptomOf data:Bọ_Xích_Dài.
?annotation data:DiseaseSite "Hat"
}
where{
 ?annotation owl:annotatedSource data:Bọ_Xích_Dài;
                            owl:annotatedProperty data:hasSymptom;
                            owl:annotatedTarget data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
}`

Comment: I do not understand ... if the object property is not there, you can add it via SPARQL as well. You can always add as many triples as you want with `INSERT DATA { all your triples here, also the annotation triples  }` - no need for `WHERE` here if there is no mathcing data already

Comment: For example I have objectproperty like this then how can I insert annotation into it`<hasSymptom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#Hạt_chuyển_sang_màu_bạc"/>`

Comment: For example I want to add DiseaseSite = "La" as below `<owl:Axiom>
<owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#Bọ_Xích_Dài"/>
<owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#hasSymptom"/>
<owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/tvanl/ontologies/2020/8/benhlua#Hạt_bị_lửng"/>
<DiseaseSite rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Hạt</DiseaseSite>
</owl:Axiom>`

Comment: Just add the triples as you already did with your `INSERT` statement? I don't understand what is not working.

Comment: That right. But when I want to add a new Objectproperty for individual with that annotations, it doesn't work. it only works if the Objectproperty is available that I added in the protege

Comment: no ... please read my comments. use `INSERT DATA { ... }` with proper full RDF triples - don't user `INSERT {} WHERE {}` which does pattern matching which of course doesn't work if the data isn't there yet

Comment: `insert DATA{
    data:Bọ_Xích_Dài data:hasSymptom data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
    data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát data:isSymptomOf data:Bọ_Xích_Dài.
    owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource data:Bọ_Xích_Dài.
    owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource data:hasSymptom. 
    owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource data:Bông_lúa_trỗ_không_thoát.
    data:DiseaseSite rdf:datatype "Lá"
};`Is this right?

Comment: But it still doesn't work. Please give me 1 example script please

Comment: I don't know what you are doing there. This is not XML, so why `rdf:resource` as predicate? The whole thing is an axiom which is the subject of all annotation triples.

Comment: it must be `INSERT DATA {s p xlt .
_:x rdf:type owl:Axiom .
_:x owl:annotatedSource s .
_:x owl:annotatedProperty p .
_:x owl:annotatedTarget xlt .}` - feel free to replace the placeholders `s`,`p` and `xlt` with your entities

Comment: Oh I understand ! Thank you very much for supporting me.

Comment: How to delete annotation bro? After I added it, I tried removing it but when I re-added it added that previous annotation and that new annotation

Comment: Put what you did before into a `DELETE DATA {}` of course